# Why is linq query not putting "where" in SQL statement

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my linq query:

```
 Dim Jobs As New DBDataContext
  Dim jobpart = Jobs.JobParts.Where(Function(x) x.JobNum = 143401).ToList
```

and this is the sql statement I'm seeing in sql profiler:

```
SELECT [t0].[JobNum], [t0].[PartNum], [t0].[UserName] FROM [dbo].[JobParts] AS [t0]
```

Why is the where statement not coming through? It's selecting all records from database and it seems to be filtering out the ones I want later on.

Update:

I created a new website with just that dataclass and same code and the "where" IS showing up in profiler. I tried adding that dataclass to my current website and the "where" is NOT showing up in profiler.  What could possibly change how Linq creates the queries between projects?

Comment: Isn't this the way linq "optimizes" - by not running expensive filters on the database but rather thinking that a loop on the client is better?

Comment: Can you include the code that defines Jobs and JobParts? That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: By calling `.ToList()` you're saying that everything beyond that point of the query will be executed locally but I would have expected that everything before it is executed in the database. Are you sure this is the entire query?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yes, that's all that shows up. I did remove a couple dozen fields to make it readable.

Comment: @ConstantCoder I put up the definition for Jobs but how would I show the definition for JobParts which is in my dbml designer?

Comment: @nlehman, there should be a Jobs.Designer.vb file (or something named similarly). You may have to view all files in the project to find it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no, LINQ 2 SQL and EF translate literally in almost all cases. It is not equipped to make such decisions. Probably, the OP accidentally switched to LINQ to objects which does not know about databases.

Comment: @nlehman Welcome to StackOverflow. Now that you figured out the answer, you should move the part of your edit that describes the answer, to make it a formal Answer so it is easier to find for future users.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. In my web config under namespaces tag I was using `<clear/>` which was getting rid of some namespace necessary for linq querying. The reason it was so hard to find was because I was manually importing the system.linq.enumerable in my vb page which was masking any errors from my "where" statement. Once I commented out that import, I started seeing an error that my class was not queryable and that I am probably missing the namespace. That's when I found the web config issue.